# Self-Join ... new synthetic columns for values in existing column

Tags: sql, self-join, full-outer-join

I did this once before but don't remember how ... I've struggled with it enough and am now looking for help.

I have a table with two columns:  Uuid and ProcessId
The ProcessId column currently has two values in it: ValueA and ValueB

I want to do a self join (full outer join?) such that with the following table:

```
        1234  ValueA
        1234  ValueB
        2345  ValueB
        3456  ValueA
```

I will have a result as follows:

```
        Uuid    ValueA      ValueB
        1234    OK          OK
        2345    Missing     OK
        3456    OK          Missing
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Uuid, 
   CASE WHEN U.ValueA>0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'Missing' END AS ValueA,
   CASE WHEN U.ValueB>0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'Missing' END AS ValueB
FROM 
 (SELECT T.Uuid, 
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable AS M WHERE T.Uuid=M.UserID AND ValueField='ValueA') AS ValueA, 
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable AS M WHERE T.Uuid=M.UserID AND ValueField='ValueB') AS ValueB
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Uuid FROM MyTable) AS T
  GROUP BY Uuid) AS U
ORDER BY Uuid
```

Comment: You are welcome.  Since you are new, it would be beneficial to mark the answer as "Answered".  Thanks.

Comment: Holger - I know this isn't the best place to ask, but I went thru the FAQ and looked thru the meta postings ... how do I mark it as Answered?

Comment: @RonAlby, click the checkmark next to the answer.  (Note, you are only allowed one answer per question.)  Thanks to asking.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on indexes, table size, and the optimizer, it might be fastest to use a pair of self-joins:

```
select TableU.Uuid, 
    if(count(TableA.ProcessId) > 0, 'OK', 'Missing') as ValueA, 
    if(count(TableB.ProcessId) > 0, 'OK', 'Missing') as ValueB 
from Table11301861 as TableU
left join Table11301861 as TableA on TableA.ProcessId = 'ValueA' and TableA.Uuid = TableU.Uuid
left join Table11301861 as TableB on TableB.ProcessId = 'ValueB' and TableB.Uuid = TableU.Uuid
group by TableU.Uuid
```